# Boxplot with Subgroups in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to make a [Boxplot with subgroups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDafV.jpg) in R.

My data looks like this:

```
Sample Point    N.conc  toc
H1  0.2 0.2
H1  0.3 0.3
H1  0.4 0.4
H1  0.3 0.3
H1  0.3 0.3
H1  0.5 0.5
H1  0.5 0.5
H1  0.4 0.4
H1  0.1 0.1
H2  0.4 0.4
H2  0.5 0.5
H2  0.5 0.6
H2  0.4 0.5
H2  0.1 0.1
H2  0.3 0.3
H2  0.4 0.4
H2  0.3 0.3
H2  0.3 0.3
H3  0.4 0.4
H3  0.5 0.8
H3  0.3 0.3
H3  0.2 0.2
H3  0.2 0.2
H3  0.4 0.4
H3  0.3 0.3
H3  0.2 0.2
H3  0.3 0.4
```

How can I make a boxplot similar to the [attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDafV.jpg)?

Comment: Hi Jofel , My question is a bit different to the Boxplot for Groups. I need the First column in the X axis . And the other two columns with respect to column 1. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I read in your data using the following:

```
df <- read.table(text='Point N.conc toc
                       H1  0.2 0.2
                       H1  0.3 0.3
                       H1  0.4 0.4
                       H1  0.3 0.3
                       H1  0.3 0.3
                       H1  0.5 0.5
                       H1  0.5 0.5
                       H1  0.4 0.4
                       H1  0.1 0.1
                       H2  0.4 0.4
                       H2  0.5 0.5
                       H2  0.5 0.6
                       H2  0.4 0.5
                       H2  0.1 0.1
                       H2  0.3 0.3
                       H2  0.4 0.4
                       H2  0.3 0.3
                       H2  0.3 0.3
                       H3  0.4 0.4
                       H3  0.5 0.8
                       H3  0.3 0.3
                       H3  0.2 0.2
                       H3  0.2 0.2
                       H3  0.4 0.4
                       H3  0.3 0.3
                       H3  0.2 0.2
                       H3  0.3 0.4',header=T)
```

You can try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df1 <- melt(df,id.vars=1)

ggplot(df1,aes(x=Point,y=value,fill=variable))+
  stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar",
               stat_params = list(width = 0.2),
               position=position_dodge(width=0.3))+
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=0.3),width=0.25)+
  ylab("mg/l")+xlab("")+labs(fill="")+theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle=0))
```

[image]

Note that most of the call to `ggplot()` was to get the answer to more closely mimic your drawing.  A sufficient boxplot could have been achieved with:

```
ggplot(df1,aes(x=Point,y=value,fill=variable))+geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Wil Give it a Try.

Comment: The above programs worked. Can Anyone tell me how do I geom_boxplot to edit colour

Comment: +  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","green"))