# Boxplot with subgroup in r with ggplot2_ error message

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to create a boxplot in r like the one reported in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896018/boxplot-with-subgroups-in-r)
 but I have problems with ggplot2 which reports an error message:

Error: Unknown parameters: stat_params

I attached my dataset..could anyone explain me how to make a boxplot similar to this?
[image]

```
Group   Biomass Area     Biomass S  
a       24917            8008
a       66669            11484
a       183804            52256
a       440343            390796
b       18552            9940
b       21718            4644
b       27365            16830
b       27437            18997
b       57743            66360
b       68698            18216
b       201322           40992
c       11650            2484
c       21491            18410
c       66388            9775
c       777336           406350
c       1420608          1137929
d       133323           105884
d       597494           398671
e       745              256.68
e       188507           401468
e       194980           71725
e       1577223          355802
f       23518            5882
f       263680           170960
f       1669782          2792580
f       3582829          2482400
```

Thanks

Comment: To the error:  make it `width = 0.2` instead of  `stat_params = list(width = 0.2)` - there have been changes in recent ggplot2 versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this ?

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.csv("test.csv")

df <- reshape2::melt(df, "Group")

ggplot(df, aes(x = Group, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar") + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]